# Yet another 'cannot find symbol' error when creating a new class object

Tags: java, class, object, instantiation, cannot-find-symbol

In short, I'm trying to instantiate within the main method in order to handle computations. I wrote the main class in Eclipse and was able to compile and run everything smoothly.

Main Method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ...

    OutsideClass class = new OutsideClass();

    ...
}
```

I ran it in eclipse, which worked smoothly until I got an error due to to insufficient privileges, which led me to switch over to using cmd.exe as an administrator.

I navigated to the eclipse folder where I had all the classes saved to and ran `javac x.java` for each file in the folder, one by one. I was able to do `javac OutsideClass.java` without any errors, though when it came to `javac Main.java`, I received the following error:

```
Main.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
                    OutsideClass outside = new OutsideClass();
                    ^
symbol:   class OutsideClass
location: class Main
Main.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
                    OutsideClass outside = new OutsideClass();
                                          ^
symbol:   class OutsideClass
location: class Main
2 errors
```

The `OutsideClass` doesn't have a defined constructor, though I don't know if that really matters or not.

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler needs the source (`.java`) or bytecode (`.class`) of `OutsideClass` when compiling `Main.java`.

Try `javac *.Java`, or `javac -cp OutsideClass.class Main.java` to provide `OutsideClass`'s definition to the compiler when compiling `Main`.

It is more customary for Java developers to compile all Java sources of a single project via one `javac` invitation, either directly, or via a tool such as [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html).